# Any workaround for NPAPI nor working on Chrome 32

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome 32 has blocked NPAPI for extension development.

I wonder if there is any workaround for enable this feature in Chrome, like some settings or launch args.

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that should have changed for extensions so far is that you can't post new extensions that include NPAPI plugins to the store. There's no setting or flag that you can use locally that would make the store policy not apply to you.

If you are seeing plugins in existing extensions not working correctly in 32, you should file a bug.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe the only thing I can do is to use Native Messaging API as an alternative. Thx!